# How to create Subquery in Jpa Specification with ManyToMany relation to get result by input parameters list?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, subquery, many-to-many, specifications

Entity models:

```
@Entity
public class Label {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "label_feature",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "label_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "feature_id"))
    private List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
@Entity
public class Feature {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "features", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<>();
```

How to correct create Specification with Subquery to get for example all fearures by input List of labels?

tried to create a subquery similar to this SQL query, but could not match the fields
SQL query:
SELECT * FROM feature where id in (select feature_id from label_feature where label_id in (SELECT id FROM label where name in ('Test 1', 'Test 2')));

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution how to do it, it may be useful to someone:

```java
private Predicate withLabels(Root<Feature> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb, Predicate predicate, List<String> labels) {
    query.distinct(true);

    Join<Feature, Label> joinTag = root.join("labels");

    Subquery<Label> labelSubQuery = query.subquery(Label.class);
    Root<Label> label = labelSubQuery.from(Label.class);
    labelSubQuery.select(label.get("id")).where(cb.trim(label.get("name")).in(labels));

    return cb.and(joinTag.get("id").in(labelSubQuery), predicate);
}
```